# Java wav sounds NullPointer

Tags: java, audio

I found this code on the Internet for playing a *.wav* file

```
  public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {       
        public void run() {
          try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            ClientMain.class.getResourceAsStream("sounds/" + url));
            clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.start(); 
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }).start();
    }
```

When I call `getAudioInputStream()` it gives me a `NullPointerException`.

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at   com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:130)                         
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1111)
at it.whispers.rain.ClientMain$10.run(ClientMain.java:415)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
at java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java:916)
at it.whispers.rain.ClientMain.send(ClientMain.java:400)
at it.whispers.rain.ClientMain.Disconnect(ClientMain.java:373)
at it.whispers.rain.ClientMain.run(ClientMain.java:319)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

EDIT:
This is what i give when the .wav file is loaded:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
  at     org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
at it.whispers.rain.ClientMain$10.run(ClientMain.java:418)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: run your code in debug mode and add a breakpoint on the line number in the class SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:130, you should be able to figure out the NPE

Comment: I suspect this line :- `ClientMain.class.getResourceAsStream("sounds/" + url)`

Comment: what is the function of ClientMain.class.getResourceAsStream?

Comment: @DavideRain: You should embed the wave file in your .jar. Since you probably haven't done that, the method cannot fetch the file and returns `null`.

Comment: The file is in a source folder in the jar file called "sounds"

Comment: Can you modify the code so you can inspect the result of that method? Perhaps you should modify your question with a tree of the .jar file as well... If the .class files are placed in some directory. The root of the resources is different...

Comment: @DavideRain: Is the file in such directory **relative** to the .class file? In other words if the .class file is in some directory, you should place the `sounds` folder as a subfolder of that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate a .jar, you can embed resource files (files that can be read out by the java runtime environment).

This line reads out files that are embedded in the .jar:

```
ClientMain.class.getResourceAsStream("sounds/" + url));
```

Since you probably haven't added a `.wav` file in the `sounds` directory of the .jar file. The method cannot fetch that file and returns `null`. The file is (in most cases) loaded **relatively** from the class file (thus `ClientMain.class`).

You can simply modify the line by opening a File from the file system, or embed a wave file.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) for more details.

---

**EDIT**: A second error is the format error. Perhaps you can solve this by fetching the format:

```
AudioFormat format = inputStream.getFormat();
```

and then:

```
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);//you should postpone the creation of the clip
```

So the full code (in the  `Thread`):

```
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(ClientMain.class.getResourceAsStream("sounds/" + url));
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
clip.open(inputStream);
clip.start();
```

Possibly you created a `Clip` that has an encoding/bitrate/... that does not correspond to the actual `.wav` file.

Comment: Ok i am trying to embed the .wav file, i should make a package called "sounds"?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on how you construct your .jar file. You can inspect a .jar file by rename it to a .zip and decompress. Can you please post (part) of the resulting file tree?

Comment: I figured it out but now i get a Invalid format error :( it is a .wav file

Comment: Well at least we made improvement :S, sorry. But this is probably because your wave file is corrupt, or the player is not really up to date...

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format this?

Comment: No, I mean can you provide the stacktrace? (updated question)

Comment: @DavideRain: Updated question. Of course errors are still possible. But we can solve these in a next iteration.